# What is Ghost Rider's (any incarnation) top speed on a motorcycle?

Tags: marvel, ghost-rider

What's Ghost Rider's top speed in any movie or comic? Some people say 160mph, others 500-700mph.

Comment: Much less opinion-based after the edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say roughly at the speed of sound. It varies with various iterations of the character, but here is one showing the relative speeds of Mjolnir and Ghost Rider.

Seeing that Thor normally flies at the speed of sound, roughly 770 miles an hour (He flies by hurling the hammer and holding onto its thong) we can surmise that Ghost Rider can ride atleast faster than speed of sound.

> Thor is capable of hurling Mjölnir with great force and, by holding onto the leather thong, is capable of flying through the air at tremendous speeds. While in an Earth-like atmosphere, Thor generally flies at roughly the Speed of Sound, roughly 770 miles per hour.

Source: http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Mjolnir

[image]
[image]

Comment: Yeah, Thor holding his leather thong while flying... Think about chris Hemsworth in a leather thong. The mcu film would draw additional  millions of women.

Comment: @Julian not just women :3